# Mongoose js - pushAll, concat arrays

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to update (in bulk) many entities.
Each entity has a field that its value is an array.
I want to concat a whole array to the existed array in mongo.
For example:
Assume we have the field 'myField', and (its value) the array saved in mongo is: [4, 5, 6]
I want to concat the array [1, 2, 3] to this field, so the result:
myField: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

I tried some options:

1. pushAll - but it is no longer available.
2. usePushEach: true, in options - not working, still get the same error:
   "Unknown modifier: $pushAll. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array"
3. I read about concat - but it is not looks compatiable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How should duplicates be handled? Do you ned `myField` to be a set or can duplicates occur?

Comment: I need duplicates, and the solution for was 'push' with 'each'. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use $addToSet to add the values to existing array and avoid the duplicates like so,

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    values: [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
]
```

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 1
},
{
  "$addToSet": {
    values: {
      "$each": [
        5,
        7,
        1,
        44
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/S3HfWajg9r_

Comment: @Ran: If this solved your issue, accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.